# Why won't this for loop append to a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

Beginner here:

I'm trying to find connections of a connection in this code, but my for loop won't append anything to the list above it.
I did originally have return at the beginning with no append and found that I was overwriting any information I found, so I have been looking at different ways.

Here's my code:

```
def get_secondary_connections(network,user):
    if user in network:
        first = network.get(user).get('Connected to') #get connection list through getting user dictionary
        second = []
        for every_person in first:
            network.get(every_person).get('Connected to').append(second)


        return second
    else: #if user isn't in network
        return None
    return network
```

Comment: Are you trying to append to `second`?  As you wrote it you are appending to `network[every_person]['Connected to']`, maybe you meant: `second.append(network.get(every_person).get('Connected to'))`

Comment: @Jkdc was right, that was what I was trying to do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

ideally you should use

second.extend(network.get(every_person).get('Connected to'))

as from your example it seems that network.get(every_person).get('Connected to') is list